# How do whitening mouthwashes work?

Tags: dentistry, mouthwash, rinsing-mouth, bleach-teeth-whitening

I am trying to achieve shiny white teeth. However, I am not trying to do laser whitening or any type of dye whitening. I have recently started using an electrical toothbrush and it was amazing. Now, I am trying to go to the next level by using mouthwashes daily to remove all the discoloration from my teeth to have a whiter look.

I started using [an Optic white mouth wash with an effective peroxide formula] for 2 weeks or so. The results were visible, but if stop using it for a day or two, I notice my teeth reversing to the previous color before using the mouth wash.

**Are whiting mouthwashes just a coating layer for teeth or does it actually remove stains? Is there a different mouthwash type that remove stains?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hydrogen peroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide) is an [oxidizing bleach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleach#Whitening). It [reacts chemically with the types of molecules that contribute to color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooth_whitening).

So, it doesn't really *remove* stains, nor does it coat anything, but it does make colorful things not-as-colorful, just like if you wash your white socks with chlorine bleach.

Comment: Is not the effect of bleach permanent, However, mouthwashes are not; I do not think.

Comment: @AnwarElhadad Yes, it's permanent, but only on whatever stain is present when it's applied. It doesn't continue to react with new stains after it's washed away.